# how to handle form data in rest webservice with jersey framework?

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I am using jersey for rest webservice. request come from client in form_data format  like that following :

```
s_data:{
        "user":"koushik",
        "id":"1240",
        "from_date":"2017-11-01",
        "to_date":"2017-11-26",
        "offset":"0",
        "limit":"1000"
       }
```

how to handle in my webservice ? my approach in web service code:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Pojo getBillDetails(Pojo data){

    return data;  
}
```

P.S: I have to use post in my assignment.

Comment: First of all, before posting question take your time and format all code and output properly. Now, second, what's the error ???

Comment: ok....my question how to parse that request ?

Comment: so.. my question is what did you tried so far ? you need to post atleast part of the code, which is being used for this POC and why did you stopped now ?? are you getting any error ? if yes, then post here, if no, then continue coding..